# Android Location update issue Huawei

Tags: android, location, huawei-mobile-services

Does anyone have experience problems with the location listener on Huawei phones (eg 8 Honor, Honor 7).

I have a background service that implements location listener but for Huawei phones it stops work after about 5-6 position updates.

I've added my app as a protected app in the phone manager.

I don’t know if these logmessages are helpful to find out what is wrong:

HwLocationPowerTracker - stop namespace.my.app location

HwLauncher - Launcher.MotionManager stopMotionAppsReco service flg 402 is unavailable

HwLauncher - Launcher.MotionManager stopMotionAppsReco service flg 403 is unavailable

HwSystemManager - HsmIntentService:last work complete! lets stop service.

Comment: I have a similar issue with other sensors. Any development on this?

Comment: No progress.....
I have sent an email to Huawei but got no answer.

Comment: Similar problem over here. I'm using the fused location provider from Google Play Services and after a while the app doesn't receive any new locations.

Comment: Same problem. Still in 2018. Fused location provider from Google Play Services

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The solution to the problem has finally been found. 
In the Manifest file

```
    <?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<manifest xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    package="My.App.Package"   
<application
android:process="My.App.Package">
</application>
```

package and android:process had to be equal (case sensitive).

When requesting the wake lock I also changed "My.App.Tag" to "LocationManagerService".

```
PowerManager pm = (PowerManager) getSystemService(Context.POWER_SERVICE);           
mWakeLock = pm.newWakeLock(PowerManager.PARTIAL_WAKE_LOCK, "LocationManagerService");
```

Other settings that are necessary is to add the app as a protected app and protect it from being caught by battery saving processes. That Can be done in the phones settings.

Comment: Can you confirm if this is still working as of today? I've tried everything and I'm getting desperate

Answer (score 0):

I did the same thing with Anders, the difference is that I did not add the process to the androidManifest.

> If you use FusedLocationProviderClient update location, you must add the google play service to the battery optimization whitelist, and turn off the automatic management (the default is on) .
> Enable 1.Auto start 2.Allow background , otherwise you will not be able to get location information from google play service

Such a pathological OEM, Developer's Nightmare - China Mobile